# Bytelandian gold coins

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am solving this problem -> http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/ . A very simple DP problem with a very straight forward DP approach.I found enough hints in the problem statement to use DP. All the test cases are running perfectly in my compiler but I am getting a WA in SPOJ. My code is as follows :

### My code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
map< long long,long long > data;
map < long long,long long> :: iterator p;
int max(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)return a;
        return b;
}
long long calc(int n)
{
    long long c;
    if(n==0 || n==1 || n==2)
        return n;
p = data.find(n);
 if(p==data.end())
 {
    c = max(n, calc(n/2) + calc(n/3) + calc(n/4));
            data.insert(p, pair < long long, long long > (n, c));
            return c;
 }
else return (*p).second;

}
int main()
{
    int t;
    long long n;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    if(t>10)return 0;
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&n);
        if(n<0 || n>1000000000)
            break;
        data.clear();
        printf("%lld",calc(n));
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I am finding it really difficult for me to figure out where I am going wrong!

A test case which contradicts my code would also do.

Comment: @PersonWhoDownvoted - I appreciate your concern. But please let me know if any part of the question is unclear. I would like to rectify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a stack overflow in `calculate`. The recursion is killing your program :-)

Or simply the fact that `calculate(1000000000)` is too much slow.

Comment: No... But I think you could optimize a little. You know that calculate(n / 2) > calculate(n / 3) > calculate(n / 4), so if calculate(2) < n/3 then it's impossible that that their sum >= n...

Comment: Other point, calculate(n) calculates c(n / 2) and c(n / 4), but c(n / 2) calculates c((n / 2) / 2). Is it reusable (even considering the / operator that truncates decimals)

Comment: I'll add that you haven't even read the comments. `awesome problem. took a while to figure it out. recursion with memoization.`. Where is the memoization in your code? The solution is probably to cache the results of calculate(x) in an associative structure with search in O(1) (a map/dictionary), with the key being x and the value being calculate(x)

Comment: @Daggerhunt Yes, it becomes instantaneous on my PC even in C#. You could use something like this: http://pokristensson.com/strmap.html . A map is a fundamental instrument in SPOJ. I'll add that perhaps it would be better if you tried SPOJ through C++, because C++ has a richer base library. C# isn't good (I did various SPOJ in C#) because their runner is too much slow in the initial loading of C#.

Comment: @xanatos...I submitted the code as C++ ... Fine I get you..I need to optimize.Yes there are overlapping subproblems, and I overlooked it. Storing the results to a map/dictionary is something absolutely new to me.Is it similar to a Hash table? Oh.. and thanks for the link..

Comment: I get almost everything what you just mentioned in your comments ... but my question is why am I getting WA .. I should get a TLE instead.. right?

Comment: @Daggerhunt Errors in SPOJ are quite random. Sadly :-)

Comment: @xanatos... I have edited my code... Tried to implement memoization using a simple 1D array first(which seems impossible because of the size of 'n').Found a solution of the problem using "map" of C++ ... I implemented it but I am still getting WA.. Why?

Comment: @Daggerhunt One of the responses speaks of an overflow problem. Try using a `long long int`

Comment: @Daggerhunt With 1billion the number should be 4243218150, so you'll need at least unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dynamic programming , store your result in an array . Since the value  can go upto 10^9, and you cann't take array of that size , just take array of size till 10^6 and store their result and rest value calculate using simple recursion .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in python

```
import sys
mydict = {}
def count(n):
    if n <= 5:
        return n
    elif n in mydict.keys():
        return mydict[n]
    else:
        k=max(n,count(n / 2) + count(n / 3) + count(n / 4))
        mydict[n]=k
        return mydict[n]

for line in sys.stdin:
    res = count(int(line))
    print(int(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, uses dp :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
map<long long int,long long int> m;
long long int dp(long long int k){
    long long int a;
    if(k==0){
        return 0;
    }
    a=m[k];
    /* if(k<12){
        return k;
    } */
    if(k<12){
        return k;
    }       
    else if(a==0){  
        a=max(k,dp(k/2)+dp(k/4)+dp(k/3));
        m[k]=a;         
    }
    return a;   

}
int main(){
    long long int n,t;
    while(scanf("%lld",&n)>0){
        t=dp(n);
        cout << t << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```